# Unable to use a nested generic procedure type in a descendant class as a method's parameter using Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
program Project4;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TGenericClass<T> = class
  public type
    THandler = procedure(aParam: T);
  end;

  TMyClass = class(TGenericClass<TObject>)
  public
    procedure DoSomething(aHandler: TMyClass.THandler);
  end;

procedure TMyClass.DoSomething(aHandler: TMyClass.THandler); // E2037 Declaration of 'DoSomething' differs from previous declaration
begin
  // code here
end;

begin
end.
```

Compilations fails with error message E2037 Declaration of 'DoSomething' differs from previous declaration. Is this a limitation of the Delphi Generics implementation?

Comment: Do you have the same error if you change `TMyClass.THandler` to `TGenericClass<TObject>.THandler`, or define a new `type` in `TMyClass` that aliases `TGenericClass<TObject>.THandler`?

Comment: I'd suggest using just `THandler` without qualification. Smells like a compiler bug.

Comment: Using just THandler produces same error

Comment: This is weird. Perhaps it's just a limitation of the design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this because THandler is on the generic base class. It looks like the compiler is battling to figure out the generic portion of THandler.

```
TMyClass = class(TGenericClass<TObject>)
public
  procedure DoSomething(aHandler: TGenericClass<TObject>.THandler);
end;

procedure TMyClass.DoSomething(aHandler: TGenericClass<TObject>.THandler); 
begin
  // code here
end;
```